# If $a_n$ is an A.P., give a closed-form formula for $a_{1}a_{2} + a_{2}a_{3} + \cdots + a_{n}a_{n +1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum to nth term of the series

$a_{1}a_{2} + a_{2}a_{3} + \cdots + a_{n}a_{n +1}$

Here $a_{n}$ is nth term of an A.P with first term a and common difference d.

To solve this i applied summation to the nth term and got
$$\frac{n[3a^{2} + 3nad + (n^{2}-1)d^{2}]}{3}$$

But there is a second form of the solution
$$\frac{[a + (n - 1)d](a + nd)[a + (n + 1)d] - (a - d)a(a + d)}{3d}$$
How to get this form

Comment: Welcome to MSE. From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: I have modified your title in order for it to be self contained without refering to the **partial sums** of a series.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit formula for the $k$th term is

$$a_k=a+(k-1)d$$

This allows to define a zero-th term $a_0=a-d$.

An essential remark is that, with this $a_0$, the formula you want to establish has the form :

$$\frac{1}{3d}\left(a_{n+2}a_{n+1}a_{n}-a_0a_1a_2\right)\tag{1}$$

Why that ?

Consider the sum :

$$\underbrace{(a_1a_2a_3 - a_0a_1a_2)}_{a_1a_2(a_3-a_0)=3da_1a_2}+\underbrace{(a_2a_3a_4-a_1a_2a_3)}_{a_2a_3(a_4-a_1)=3da_2a_3}+\cdots$$

$$\cdots + \underbrace{(a_{n+2}a_{n+1}a_n - a_{n+1}a_na_{n-1})}_{a_na_{n+1}(a_{n+2}-a_{n-1})=3da_na_{n+1}}\tag{2}$$

- On one hand, (2) is equal to the sum $$3d(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+...+a_na_{n+1})$$
- On the other hand, (2) is a telescopic sum, i.e., all terms can be cancelled, but an initial and a final term, which, up to the $3d$ common factor, give exactly awaited expression (1).

Comment: Besides, your *own* expression is exact, I have checked it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You haven't said if this answer is satisfying you..

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was really helpful for     me.Thanks again.